# PHP retorno função

Tags: php

Apesar da variável `url` estar retornando conteúdo, conforme VAR_DUMP, o código abaixo sai pela mensagem "URL inexistente". Por que isso? Onde estou pecando no código?

```
public function getUrlcliente($cliente_id) {

        $parametro = "cliente_id=" . (int)$cliente_id;
        $url_externa = $this->db->query("SELECT DISTINCT query as indice, keyword as url FROM url_alias WHERE query = '" . $parametro . "'");

        if (empty($url_externa)) {
            $url = "Erro - URL amigável não cadastrada";
        }
        else {
            foreach ($url_externa as $row) {
                var_dump($row);
                if (isset($row->url)) {
                    $pos = strpos($row->url, "www");
                    if ($pos == false) {
                    }
                    else {
                        $url = $row->url;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                else {
                    $url = "Url inexistente";  ---> ele está saindo aqui
                }
            }
        }

        if ($url_externa->num_rows) {
                    return $url;
                }
        else
                {
                    return "Erro-Url inexistente";
                }
}
```

o VAR_DUMP está retornando isso ---->

> int(1) array(2) { ["indice"]=> string(13) "cliente_id=42" ["url"]=> string(21) "http://www.uol.com.br" } array(1) { [0]=> array(2) { ["indice"]=> string(13) "cliente_id=42" ["url"]=> string(21) "http://www.uol.com.br" } }

Percebam que o objetivo da função é retornar apenas uma string, a URL, não quero que retorne um array.

Comment: Já tentou tentou pegar o valor assim `$row["url"]` ?

Comment: @Augusto era isso. Obrigado.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Segue a solução abaixo pegando o resultado da array `$row`

```
public function getUrlcliente($cliente_id) {
    $parametro = "cliente_id=" . (int)$cliente_id;
    $url_externa = $this->db->query("SELECT DISTINCT query as indice, keyword as url FROM url_alias WHERE query = '" . $parametro . "'");

    if (empty($url_externa)) {
        $url = "Erro - URL amigável não cadastrada";
    } else {
        foreach ($url_externa as $row) {
            if (isset($row['url'])) {
                $pos = strpos($row['url'], "www");
                if ($pos !== false) {
                    $url = $row['url'];
                    break;
                }
            } else {
                $url = "Url inexistente";  ---> ele está saindo aqui
            }
        }
    }

    if ($url_externa->num_rows) {
        return $url;
    } else {
        return "Erro-Url inexistente";
    }
}
```

Comment: MSergio se a solução do Augusto resolver seu problema, pode marcar a resposta como aceita depois, de forma a aparecer como resolvida na listagem do site. Quando for coisa que admite várias respostas, é sempre bom esperar um tempo maior, para escolher a mais adequada, mas nesse caso aqui acho que não tem muito o que mudar.